# Map with Optional Unwrapping in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, option-type, unwrap

Say I had the below api :

```
func paths() -> [String?] {
    return ["test", nil, "Two"]
}
```

And I was using this in a method where I needed `[String]`, hence I had to unwrap it using the simple `map` function. I'm currently doing :

```
func cleanPaths() -> [String] {
    return paths.map({$0 as! String})
}
```

Here, the force-cast will cause an error. So technically I need to unwrap the Strings in the `paths` array. I'm having some trouble doing this and seem to be getting silly errors. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`compactMap()` can do this for you in one step:

```
let paths:[String?] = ["test", nil, "Two"]

let nonOptionals = paths.compactMap{$0}
```

`nonOptionals` will now be a String array containing `["test", "Two"]`.

Previously `flatMap()` was the proper solution, but has been deprecated for this purpose in Swift 4.1

Comment: Kudos for digging this function from the trench of Swift's undocumented higher-order functions!

Comment: @ZoffDino - Credit for this should belong to Airspeed Velocity: http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/06/23/protocol-extensions-and-the-death-of-the-pipe-forward-operator/ who first pointed this out to me.

Comment: I've been playing with Swift for 9 months and still couldn't find a complete list of higher order functions in the language. Apple has a lot to catch up on this front.

Comment: [Optional `map()` here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Optional_Enumeration/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015225-CH1-DontLinkElementID_8), [Sequence here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015890-CH1-DontLinkElementID_27)

Comment: Note: this works in Swift 2. For 1.2, use `return paths.filter({$0 != nil}).map({$0 as String!})`

Answer (score 5):

You should filter first, and map next:

```
return paths.filter { $0 != .None }.map { $0 as! String }
```

but using `flatMap` as suggested by @BradLarson is a just better

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you want to is a `filter` followed by a `map`:

```
func cleanPaths() -> [String] {
    return paths()
            .filter {$0 != nil}
            .map {$0 as String!}
}

let x = cleanPaths()
println(x) // ["test", "two"]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let name = obj.value
name.map { name  in print(name)}
```